# Convert lowercase letter to upper case in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a [code](http://www.liewcf.com/archives/2004/04/javascript-convert-characters-to-uppercase-when-typing/) that will convert lower case letters to uppercase but it works only with IE and not in Crome or Firefox.

```
function ChangeToUpper()
  {         
            key = window.event.which || window.event.keyCode;

            if ((key > 0x60) && (key < 0x7B))
            window.event.keyCode = key-0x20;
  }



<asp:TextBox ID="txtJobId" runat="server" MaxLength="10" onKeypress="ChangeToUpper();"></asp:TextBox>
```

Even I tried with

```
document.getElementById("txtJobId").value=document.getElementById("txtJobId").value.toUpperCase();
```

**onBlur event of the textbox**

What should I do to make it work in all browsers?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeCase(elem)
    {
        elem.value = elem.value.toUpperCase();
    }
</script>
<input onblur="ChangeCase(this);" type="text" id="txt1" />
```

separate javascript from your HTML

```
window.onload = function(){
        var textBx = document.getElementById ( "txt1" );

        textBx.onblur = function() {
            this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
        };
    };

<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

If the textbox is inside a naming container then use something like this

```
var textBx = document.getElementById ("<%= txt1.ClientID %>");

            textBx.onblur = function() {
                this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
            };)
```

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried `.toUpperCase()`?

Links:

- [Formatting text using JavaScript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/string2.shtml)
- [JAVASCRIPT toUpperCase() METHOD](http://www.toknowmore.net/e/1/javascript/javascript-touppercase.php)

Comment: Too hard, dude! Is way easier to write a function from scratch :D

Comment: @Priyanka - What is error you receive on the function? It makes no sense for the base function not to work. @lonut - lol :P

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to make an explicit JavaScript function, here you can do it in just one line:

Convert to lower and upper case respectively:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" onblur='this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" onblur='this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();'></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use CSS and do `text-transform:uppercase` and on submit you run [toUppercase()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toUpperCase.asp). Or you just submit as mixed and you capitalize letters on server side :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest way is..

```
<input id="yourid" style="**text-transform: uppercase**" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var myString = "this is a String";
alert(myString.toUpperCase()); // "THIS IS A STRING"
alert(myString.toLowerCase()); // "this is a string"
```

Thanks... Hope you like it.