# From lowercase to upper case

Tags: php, javascript, html

hey, I trying to enter the text in lowercase letter but when it comes to textbox it must be in uppercase if anyone can do this.

Comment: Do you want to insert the value with PHP or do you want to modify it with JavaScript?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with CSS, no need for JavaScript or PHP

```
text-transform:uppercase
text-transform:lowercase
```

Add these to the style of each element class.

Or if you are resorting to inline styling, do this.

```
<input type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase;" />
```

Comment: @Crowder: I know. its just that then i may have to edit this answer a bit

Answer (score 3):

String to uppercase with PHP ([php.net doc](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtoupper.php)):

```
strtoupper("Hello")

Output: HELLO
```

String to uppercase with JavaScript ([java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0120__String/stringtoUpperCase.htm)):

```
var s = new String("Hello")
s.toUpperCase()

Output: HELLO
```

Answer (score 1):

Your options are:

1. [As Raoul said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236345/from-lowercase-to-upper-case/6236369#6236369), use CSS. If you possibly can, this is your best bet.
2. Let the user type in lower case, then transform it when they leave the field (`blur`, etc.) or when you save/process the text (e.g., on the server, whatever). Here's a `blur` example:

   ```
   document.getElementById('theIDOfTheTextArea').onblur = function() {
       this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
   };
   ```

   [Live example](http://jsbin.com/ohema5)
3. Do it with JavaScript in the `keydown` or `keypress` event. Despite the various attempts intermittently posted here, doing this with JavaScript ***not trivial***. It's trivial to identify the keypresses you want to handle and to cancel the event to prevent that keypress being added; but then inserting the character you *do* want is non-trivial. (Sadly, the keyboard events *don't* just let you substitute a different character; that would be nice, but they don't.) It unfortunately requires that you use text ranges / selections and gets you into areas that vary cross-browser. You'd probably need to leverage a library like [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) to do it. I'd Just Say No and go the CSS / post-processing route.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354716/convert-lowercase-letter-to-upper-case-in-javascript) will solve your problem.

- Get the textbox element by id
- Set an onBlur listener and convert its value using string.toUpperCase()

Answer (score 0):

Have you check this

[Upper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354716/convert-lowercase-letter-to-upper-case-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#idoftextbox").blur(function(){$(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase())});
```

Put this in an onload event

Comment: BTW this solution requires jquery

Comment: I would really know why I got a down vote for this.  Here is a working example with source code http://jsfiddle.net/xrthX/

Answer (score -1):

Easy:

```
textareaElement.onkeydown = function(e) {
    //make sure IE gets it
    e = e || event;
    //don't insert
    e.preventDefault();
    //catch the ASCII key code, and convert it to uppercase letter
    this.value += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: A few problems there. 1. You're using `preventDefault` in a DOM0-style handler, which may not work (and won't work at all on browsers like IE8 and earlier that don't *have* `preventDefault`). 2. You're happily assuming every keypress results in a character (so, arrow keys are a bit of an issue). 3. You're assuming all characters should go to the end of the text. 4. You're assuming `keyCode` holds an ASCII value in lower case, which it doesn't: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html 5. You're not checking whether the character is shifted or not (related to, but different from, point 4).