# Making the p element show in upper case using the toUpperCase method

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can tell from my code. I am very new to this so, please try to keep your answers simple.

The assignment was to make the whatever name is entered comes back in uppercase which I did.

But I want everything to show in uppercase, both the name and paragraph. I have tried everything that I can think of, I feel like it's something simple.

This is what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#letter form").submit(function(event) {
  var nameInput = $("input#name").val().toUpperCase();

  $(".name1").text(nameInput);
  $("#response").show();


  event.preventDefault();

  });
});
```

```css
#response {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"-->


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="js/scripts.js"></script-->

<div class="container">
<h1>Fill in the blanks to write your story!</h1>
<div id="letter">
 <form>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">A name</label>
     <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text">
   </div>

   <button type="submit" class="btn">Show me the response</button>
 </form>
</div>

<div id="response">
 <h1>A fantastical adventure</h1>
 <blockquote>
 <p><span class="name1"></span>, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</blockquote>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Certainly a cut and paste error here only... But your jQuery and BootStap external `script` calls are reversed. Put jQuery before Bootstrap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert lowercase letter to upper case in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354716/convert-lowercase-letter-to-upper-case-in-javascript)

Comment: yeah that's a copy and paste error. thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want it for ALL your `<p>` tags, you [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) follow the same rules as CSS selectors. With this in mind you can get the `innerText` with [jQuery .text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
// Select ALL p tags, and set their text to upper case
$('p').text($('p').text().toUpperCase());
```

If you want it specifically for the first parent paragraph that contains a child with the class `name1` we can use a similar idea with [jQuery .closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
// Split into a var to help readability
// Grab the "closest ancestor" (get the first parent that is a p)
var closestP = $('.name1').closest('p');
closestP.text(closestP.text().toUpperCase());
```

I hope this is what you're looking for!

Edit: Another way that requires editing the html for that specific`p`:

**HTML**

```
<div id="response">
   <h1>A fantastical adventure</h1>
   <blockquote>
   <p id="toCapital"><span class="name1"></span>, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </blockquote>
 </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#toCapital').text($('#toCapital').text().toUpperCase());
```

Here I used a similar idea to the first example, except instead of selecting ALL paragraph tags, I added an `id` to the existing one, selected that, and then modified the text.

You could also do a little more advanced selection, but this will not select the same paragraph that you want to capitalize if you add any more beforehand:

```
var first = $('p').first();
first.text(first.text().toUpperCase());
```

I'm sure you can see where I'm going with these, the key is to think about how you can identify what you want to change, it's tricky at first but it gets easier as you start to understand the differences between `name`, `class`, `id`, as well as the other attributes and how you can combine them to create unique combinations.

Comment: Ah I thought I asked this, guess not. Can you explain why "$('p').text()." is there twice? I actually think I tried writing it as  $('p').text().toUpperCase(); before I submitted the code on here.

I did look up some reading material. I even asked my teacher, but he didn't do a good job at explaining it.

Thanks!

Comment: @rainbowpudding sorry for the late response: The first one `$('p').text( ... )` is actually a setter for the value, and the one inside it `$('p').text().toUpperCase()` gets the current value and changes it to upper case. [jQuery .text() docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

To make ALL the response to uppercase:

```
$("#response").html($("#response").html().toUpperCase());
```

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) sets and returns all the text and markup of the element selected...
It's on the biggest container `$("#response")` that you have to apply the [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) method.

See below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#letter form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var nameInput = $("input#name").val().toUpperCase();
    $(".name1").text(nameInput);

    $("#response").html($("#response").html().toUpperCase());
    $("#response").show();

  });
});
```

```css
#response {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"-->



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="js/scripts.js"></script-->

<div class="container">
<h1>Fill in the blanks to write your story!</h1>
<div id="letter">
 <form>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">A name</label>
     <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text">
   </div>

   <button type="submit" class="btn">Show me the response</button>
 </form>
</div>

<div id="response">
 <h1>A fantastical adventure</h1>
 <blockquote>
 <p><span class="name1"></span>, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</blockquote>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and answering my question!

Comment: Consider accepting the answer (click on the green checkmark) if you are satisfied of it. ;)